# Is there a way to use multiple vim folding methods at once?

Tags: vim

I have `foldmethod=indent` set in my `~/.vimrc`, and in general that works for me and I'd like to keep it.

However, there are a few files I have which I edit regularly (and which are under my exclusive control), where I'd like to add in a marker-based system, in particular so that when I open the file a large section I rarely look at (which is already 'delimited' by indent) is pre-folded. It looks like `foldmethod=marker` would allow me to do that (I don't mind the odd comment in the file to indicate these 'pre-folds' if necessary), but I still want `foldmethod=indent` set so that I can use `zc`, `zo`, and so on to then fold or unfold sections by indent. As far as I can tell I can't set foldmethod to multiple values.

Is there another way I can achieve this (ideally using something embedded in the file itself)?

Comment: I'm also trying to get both fold methods of marker and indent working at the same time. I also believe that to use the fold expression is the best option. Did you find an expression to match both indent and marker?

Comment: @Jp_ nope, 'fraid not.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Each *window* can have its own local value of `'foldmethod'`; what you set in `~/.vimrc` is just the global default. There are multiple ways to set a different local value for a particular *buffer*:

1. Manually with `:setlocal foldmethod=marker`
2. For a particular filetype (e.g. Java files): `:autocmd FileType java setlocal foldmethod=marker` (or in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/java.vim`)
3. For particular file(s): `:autocmd BufRead /path/to/file setlocal foldmethod=marker`
4. Inside the file itself via a *modeline* (since you have to add the markers anyway, I would prefer this):

```
/* vim: set fdm=manual : */
```

---

There still can be only one fold method *inside* a single window. If you want to employ different strategies, you have to choose a more flexible method (e.g. `expr`), and re-implement the "other" method(s) in there (e.g. by making your `'foldexpr'` consider the indent). Or you use two window splits for the same buffer, and set different foldmethods for each split.

Since that probably isn't what you want to hear, you could hack something together with an `:autocmd CursorMoved` that switches the foldmethod based on the current line:

```
" Use markers when in the first 100 lines, else use indent.
:autocmd CursorMoved,CursorMovedI <buffer> let &l:foldmethod = (line('.') <= 100 ? 'manual' : 'indent')
```

Comment: Thanks. So this tells me I can set foldmethod to marker inside that buffer. But what I'm looking for is something that still allows me to use the indent foldmethod, whilst have some sections (which _are_ delimited by an indent) pre-folded. If I do (4) above, `zc`, `zo`, and so on will no longer work as intended in that buffer. I've clarified my question.

Comment: Your question wasn't clear in that aspect, thanks for the clarification. I've amended my answer.

Comment: Yes, apologies if I wasn't clear. The foldexpr sounds like the best approach but also complicated. I'll give it a try though. +1 for the pointer.

Comment: Thanks again. I have been trying to write the foldexpr and opened a related Q here which may be of interest: http://superuser.com/questions/560167/how-can-i-write-a-vim-foldexpr-which-is-equivalent-to-foldmethod-indent

Comment: @IngoKarkat: In the first paragraph below the line you wrote that there can be only one fold method _per buffer_. I believe that should be _per window_.

Comment: @garyjohn: Okay, I've reworded it. The question actually starts with that it's window-local; I meant single buffer here.

Comment: @IngoKarkat: But you _can_ have more than one foldmethod in a single buffer. You just can't have more than one foldmethod at a time in a single window. E.g., edit some file; execute `:split`; in one window execute `:set foldmethod=manual`; in the other window execute `:set foldmethod=marker`. Now execute `:windo set foldmethod=?`. You'll see that those two windows into the _same buffer_ have _different_ foldmethods.

Comment: @garyjohn: I know, I even mentioned this in my answer.