# How can I write a vim foldexpr which is equivalent to foldmethod=indent?

Tags: vim

As a result of [this answer here](https://superuser.com/a/560154/3021), I'm trying to write a `foldexpr` for vim which is equivalent to `foldmethod=indent` (as a starting point to then enhancing it to recognise my custom markers, [see the question for more details](https://superuser.com/questions/560149/is-there-a-way-to-use-multiple-vim-folding-methods-at-once)).

I've tried this:

```
set foldmethod=foldexpr
set foldexpr=indent(v:lnum)
```

However, this fails on this simple HTML example:

```
<div id="a">
    <div id="b">
        <div id="c">
            <div id="d">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="e">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If I place my key on the `<div id="c">` line, and hit `zc`, the fold works as expected and folds only that div. If I re-open, then place my key on the `<div id="b">` line, and hit `zc`, the fold fails as `<div id="e">` is not folded.

If I switch to `foldmethod=indent`, this doesn't happen; the second fold is performed correctly. How can I fix my `foldexpr` to make it behave like `foldmethod=indent`?

Comment: Have you managed to get multiple foldmethods (marker and indent) working together using this approach?

Comment: @blueyed, I'm afraid not. I put this project on hold for the time being. Would be interested to hear if you have any success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Empty lines should keep the fold level of the previous line. Try this:

```
:set foldmethod=expr
:set foldexpr=empty(getline(v:lnum))?'=':indent(v:lnum)/4
```